# Как пропатчить KDE2 под FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, linux

Как пропатчить KDE2 под FreeBSD?

Comment: Вопрос был актуален пару лет назад)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd /usr/ports && make index; pkgdb -F
cd /usr/ports/x11/xorg && make all install && make clean
cd /usr/ports/x11/kde3/
make && make install && make clean;
portsnap fetch
portsnap extract
portsnap fetch update
xorgcfg
cp ~/xorg.conf.new /usr/X11R6/etc/X11/xorg.conf
touch ~/.xinitrc && echo -ne “exec startkde” > ~/.xinitrc
reboot
startx
```

с [лрк](http://lurkmore.ru)